# how can i conver a list of unix time stamps to list of human readable date

Tags: python

```
for i in new_list:
   print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(i/1000000))
```

`new_list` is a list of unix time stamps in micro seconds. I want every element of the list to be converted to normal date time. I am getting the error

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"..Please help me out

Comment: What is normal date time? What is in `new_list`?

Comment: new_list is a list of various unix time stamps.I would like to convert new_list to human readable date.

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates that you're trying to divide a string by an integer, which doesn't work.

You need to cast `i` to an `int`:

```
for i in new_list:
    print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", time.localtime(int(i)/1000000))
```

Comment: Thanks Nolen.That Worked.Thanks a lot

Comment: @nolenroyalty Does dividing a time object `time` by an arbitrary int make any sense?

Comment: i actually wanted to convert unixtime stamp in microseconds to seconds and then passed as an input to time.localtime(). so i divided it by 100000

Comment: @venkatsai that makes sense. :)

Comment: @MichalFrystacky to be clear, the division is *within* the localtime constructor, not after it

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do it:

```
import datetime

for i in new_list:
    print(
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int(i[:-3])
        ).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000')
    )
```